# XMLHttpRequest onError too late

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest to upload a file (in [jQuery File Upload Plugin 3.7.1](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) - yes, I know it's quite an old version of this plugin).

On server side I am returning 501 error code in some cases (during the upload, not after!), so I would expect upload to stop and invoke onError. But while onError is invoked indeed, the upload itself continues. I could cancel the upload in onError, but the biggest problem is that onError is invoked **after** upload has finished.

Is there any way for me to stop the upload when there is an error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should end the response from server to stop upload.

something like     `Response.End()`